# Envoy INVALID_ARGUMENT:static_resources.clusters[0].hosts[0]: invalid name url: Cannot find field

Tags: proxy, envoyproxy

I'm using Istio pilot-agent proxy in OpenShift cluster.

I have an error **(INVALID_ARGUMENT:static_resources.clusters[0].hosts[0]: invalid name url: Cannot find field....**

Config:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8080 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          stat_prefix: egress_http
          use_remote_address: true
          codec_type: AUTO
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local-services
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/service-a" }
                route: { cluster: service-a }
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
  clusters:
  - name: service-a
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    # dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    lb_policy: round_robin
    type: strict_dns
    hosts:
    - url : tcp://service-a.apps-stage.vm.mos.cloud.sbrf.ru:80
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell with Envoy, the error "Cannot find field" means that you requested a field name (in this case, `url`) in a data structure, but Envoy doesn't support that field name in that data structure.

The "hosts" block, in your example, would look like:

```
hosts:
- socket_address:
    address: "service-a.apps-stage.vm.mos.cloud.sbrf.ru"
    port_value: 80
```